# Declare array in bash/shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am confused about how to declare an array in bash.

Presume:

```
$arr[1]=x
$arr[2]=y
$arr[3]=z
```

Code:

```
declare -A/-a object
fo var in ${arr[@]}
do
    object["a"]="${arr[1]}"
    object["b"]="${arr[2]}"
    object["c"]="${arr[3]}"
    echo ${object["a"]}
done
```

Output: z

What I want is :x

If I commented `object["b"]` and `object["c"]`, then the output is correct：x

No matter -A or -a, still does not work. is this problem related to my bash environment?

GNU bash,version 3.2.57(1) -release (x86_64_apple-darwin18)

Comment: Put a valid shebang on your code and paste it at https://shellcheck.net for validation.recommendation.

Comment: Upper case `-A` to declare an associative array (Has to be done before use, unlike regular ones)

Comment: I saw some duplicates here in S.O. so I deleted my answer twice :-)

Answer (score 0):

The indexed array requires the subscript must be evaluated to a number. In this case, `object["a"] object["b"] object["c"]` is treated as `object[0] object[0] object[0]`
Associate array can be used if the key is an arbitrary string. To declare it using `-A` instead of `-a`

> -a  Each name is an indexed array variable (see Arrays above).
>
> -A  Each name is an associative array variable (see Arrays above).

Comment: not worked, please see my update